# Get minimum value between two columns for each row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, min

This is my data table:

```
| uid |   date   | visit | transactionDate |
+-----+----------+-------+-----------------+
|  1  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     6/9/2014    |
|  1  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     8/4/2014    |
|  2  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     8/2/2014    |
|  2  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     10/17/2014  |
|  2  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     10/20/2014  |
|  3  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     6/9/2014    |
|  3  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     6/10/2014   |
|  3  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     6/11/2014   | 
|  3  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     6/12/2014   |
|  3  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     6/14/2014   |
|  3  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     6/15/2014   |
|  3  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     6/17/2014   |
|  3  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     6/18/2014   |
|  3  | 6/2/2014 |   1   |     6/23/2014   |
```

I am trying to write a query to pull the minimum of the two columns date and transaction date. Is there a way to do something like MIN(date, transactionDate)? The query should select something like this:

```
uid 1 then minimum of date and transaction_dt
uid 2 then min date and transaction_dt
```

Comment: Are you trying to find a minimum for each row or for all records?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the LEAST function?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) condition.

```
SELECT uid, visit, 
   CASE WHEN date < transactionDate THEN date ELSE transactionDate END AS minDate
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [**LEAST()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function with **MIN()** function.

Try this:

```
SELECT a.uid, MIN(LEAST(a.date, a.transaction_dt)) tdate 
FROM tableA a 
GROUP BY a.uid;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT a.uid, MIN(a.tdate) tdate
FROM (SELECT a.uid, MIN(a.date) tdate FROM tableA a GROUP BY a.uid
      UNION 
      SELECT a.uid, MIN(a.transaction_dt) tdate FROM tableA a GROUP BY a.uid
     ) AS a
GROUP BY a.uid;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for minimum per row:

```
select uid,visit,least(date,transactionDate) as minDate from t;
```

If you're looking for minimum per uid group:

```
select uid,sum(visit) as totalVisits,min(least(date,transactionDate)) as minDate
  from t
  group by uid;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT UID ,MIN(tdate) FROM 
       (SELECT a.uid, a.date tdate FROM tableA a 
      UNION 
      SELECT a.uid, a.transaction_dt tdate FROM tableA a ) AS tABLE2 T GROUP BY T.UID
```