# Search minimum price from two columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have two columns regular price and sale price. I have to search min price product from both two columns.

```
$products = $products->whereBetween('ecommerce_sku.regular_price', [$minPrice, $maxPrice]);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27372259/2943403

Answer (score 0):

```
$productRegular = $products->whereBetween('ecommerce_sku.regular_price',
          [$minPrice, $maxPrice])->orderBy('regular_price')->take(1)->get();

$productSale = $products->whereBetween('ecommerce_sku.sale_price',
          [$minPrice, $maxPrice])->orderBy('sale_price')->take(1)->get();
```

- Sort the data by price and then fetch the top most.

You will get the one with the lowest price in the given range

Compare and get the smaller one.

```
  $smallerValue=  $productRegular->regular_price> $productSale->sale_price?
  $productSale->sale_price:  $productRegular->regular_price
```

You can have case statement to get the smaller value as well.

Comment: no that's not the problem. i have to compare two columns and get minimum from two columns. one column is 'ecommerce_sku.regular_price' and second column is 'ecommerce_sku.sale_price'

Answer (score 0):

So your code will return a list of all the products that their price is between the two values. If you want to get the lowest price, then order it by the price and get the first one:

```
$product = $products
    ->whereBetween('ecommerce_sku.regular_price', [$minPrice, $maxPrice])
    ->orderBy('ecommerce_sku.regular_price', 'asc')
    ->first();
```

This will now be the product with lowest price. Does this makes sense to you?

Comment: i have another column where i have to find minimum price from both of them. that columns is 'ecommerce_sku.sale_price'.

Comment: @UmerAjmal then order by that column, and then take the first one.

Comment: @UmerAjmal btw, the code above expects that you use the Query Builder to make the query. I don't know if the `$products` is an instance of a Collection or Query Builder. If it is a Collection, then you should use `sortBy`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the lowest price of both columns, you could do:

```
$product = Product::orderByRaw('LEAST(regular_price, sale_price) asc')
               ->first();
```

This will bring the product with the minimum `regular_price` or `sale_price`.